# Manipular matriz no mathematica

Tags: matriz, mathematica

Bom dia, estou tentando fazer no mathematica uma matriz a partir de outras matrizes, Tenho:
`{{{{a,b,c}, {d,e,f}, {g,h,i}},{{j,k,l},{m,n,o},{p,q,r}}},{{{j,m,p},{k,n,q},{l,o,r}}, {{s,t,u},{v,ww,x},{y,z,zz}}}}`

[image: matriz que tenho]

e gostaria de obter:

`{{a,b,c,j,k,l},{d,e,f,m,n,o},{g,h,i,p,q,r},{j,m,p,s,t,u},{k,n,q,v,ww,x},{l,o,r,y,z,zz}}`

[Link para a imagem da matriz que eu quero](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a33do8h6pewk63t/Quero.jpg?dl=0)

(não consegui colocar a imagem, pois o imgur está rejeitando não sei porque)

Tem um jeito fácil de conseguir isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função `ArrayFlatten` faz exatamente o que você precisa.

```
matrizDeMatrizes <- {{{{a,b,c}, {d,e,f}, {g,h,i}},{{j,k,l},
{m,n,o},{p,q,r}}},{{{j,m,p},{k,n,q},{l,o,r}}, 
{{s,t,u},{v,ww,x},{y,z,zz}}}}
matrizGerada <- ArrayFlatten[matrizDeMatrizes]
```

Comment: Muito obrigada!!!